# Is there a function in react-navigation that allows me to check what the next route will be before it updates the UI?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

When I route somewhere in my navigation, I want to execute a function BEFORE the screen displays...this function will change the theme of the application. We do have the `onStateChange` on the NavigationContainer, however I need a listener function like `onBeforeStateChange(): { nextRoute, currentRoute }`

Example routing scenario:

1. Start on: Homepage (theme: Home - Colours: Black, White)
2. Route to: Profilepage (them: Profile - Colours: Blue, White)
3. Route back to: Homepage (theme: Home - Colours: Black, White)

I've been able to replicate this functionality using the `NavigationContainer.onStateChange` prop which allows me to use the following logic to change the theme based on the route:

```
<NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
      onReady={() =>
        (routeNameRef.current = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name)
      }
      onStateChange={() => {
        /**
         * The below logic ensures the right theme is being used.
         * This func can hold any GOOGLE ANALYTICS methods.
         */
        const previousRouteName = routeNameRef.current;
        const currentRouteName = navigationRef.current.getCurrentRoute().name;

        if (
          previousRouteName !== currentRouteName &&
          AVAILABLE_THEMES.includes(currentRouteName)
        ) {
          setTheme(currentRouteName);
        }

        routeNameRef.current = currentRouteName;
      }}>
```

This bit of code works fine EXCEPT for the fact that there is a delay in the Theme change. The new theme is set ONCE state changes, not just before it changes. If I were able to run a similar function to componentWillReceiveProps in my NavigationContainer then this would allow me to change the theme BEFORE the next route shows (removing the delay of the theme change which looks ugly)

The `setTheme();` method is from a HOC component. Here is the HOC and React context provider I'm using:

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { THEMES } from 'theme/colors';


const ThemeContext = createContext();

const ThemeContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [themeID, setThemeID] = useState(THEMES[0].key);

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ themeID, setThemeID }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

const withTheme = (Component) => {
  return (props) => {
    const { themeID, setThemeID } = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const getTheme = (tID) => THEMES.find((t) => t.key === tID);
    const setTheme = (tID) => setThemeID(tID);
    let theme = getTheme(themeID);
    // Return a default theme if none was found
    if (!theme) {
      theme = THEMES[0];
    }

    return (
      <Component {...props} themes={THEMES} theme={theme} setTheme={setTheme} />
    );
  };
};
```

My Homepage and Profilepage are both wrapped in the `withTheme` HOC. At the moment the theme will change AFTER the navigation state has changed, I'd love to be able to change the theme JUST BEFORE the navigation goes to the next screen (instead of it changing once the next screen is actually shown)

Questions:

- Have I over complicated things with trying to handle the theming on the react-navigation level OR am I on the right route?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme by calling the function that changes the theme color just before calling prop.navigation.navigate("Home").

If you are using Button/Touchables/Pressable to navigate. You can call the theme change function in the onPress prop before calling navigation.navigate() function. This will definitely change the theme before loading the new screen. If in case the theme changes before the screen changes. You can stick a loading indicator function before the theme function. So, the structure is as follows:

1. setIsLoading(true) // shows loading indicator
2. changeTheme() // changes the theme while the loading indicator is shown.
3. navigation.navigate("Home") // changes the screen

And to be sure they run in that exact order, since JavaScript is asynchronous, you can make the functions Promises or callbacks, so they await the return of the current function before running the next function.

Alternatively, you can add this function to each screen and it will run as soon as the screen loads:

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const changeTheme = changeThemeColor(() => {  ...Theme function logic... });
      return () => changeTheme();
    }, [])
  );
```

This function runs when the screen comes into focus.

You can also add a loading indicator to hide the screen while the theme function executes after the screen has been loaded and render the screen after the theme function returns. This is easily achieved with React.useState()